# Can I Use EditText onClickListener, OnTouchListener And TextWatcher At The Same Time?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, android-textwatcher

I search about this, but didn't find an answer on on any sites.
I'm curios about this one, because I implement `onTouchListener` and `TextWatcher`. And I'm having problem with `EditText` with drawable right for password (clickable drawable to show/hide password). I cannot write password on it.

I plan to put the `onTouchListener` inside the `onClickListener` but hesitate to do it, for the thought their will be conflict on Listeners.

**My question is can I used them all at the same time the** `onClickListener` , `onTouchListener`, and `TextWatcher`. For handling only just in case I need these Listeners.

I will just post my code, Here's my sample code for `onTouchListener`.

```
edtRegPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (event.getX() >= (edtRegPassword.getRight() - edtRegPassword.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        showPassword();
                    } else {
                        hidePassword();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**NOTE:** I removed the picture and some code. Already been answered.

Comment: `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is same as clicking, why don't you handle `ACTION_DOWN` and others  instead.

Comment: Many Thank you for the correction. MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is same as clicking? And MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is ...?

Comment: `ACTION_DOWN` means pressed gesture started, Have you tried that ?

Comment: Thank you Shree, I will search for that documentation.

Comment: Feel free to ask, If any issue occurred with that.